# Selenium unsupported command

Tags: selenium

I am unable to run my automation script on chrome, its showing some kind of error like:

> You are using unsupported command-line-flag:--ignore--certificate--errors.stability and security will suffer.

Comment: initially my script is running but whenever new window is opened its showing me this kind of error: DISABLE DEVELOPER MODE EXTENTION

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the command-line switch to your `ChromeOptions()`.

In python, it looks like this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
switches = ["ignore-certificate-errors"]
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", switches)
chrome = options.to_capabilities()
```

Then pass the `chrome` variable to the initialisation of your `ChromeDriver` object.

Obviously if you're not using python you'll need to alter the above to suite the bindings that you use.

Comment: initially my script is running but whenever new window is opened its showing me this kind of error: DISABLE DEVELOPER MODE EXTENTION